# How to convert FFT magnitude of square wave to dBm?

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, signal-processing

I wish to convert the FFT magnitude of square wave into dBm. I use FFT to covert voltage of square wave to a complex number, then i absolute the complex number into magnitude. Then i divide the magnitude by 2048. convert the magnitude to dBm:

$$FFT(A)= \frac{abs((fft(A))}{2048}$$

$$10\log ( \frac{(\frac{FFT(A)^2}{50})}{1mW})$$

is this correct? Can anyone correct me? What 1st harmonic and 2nd harnonic amplitude calculation? thank you.

Comment: Is this a Math or Physics question?

Comment: It seems to be nicely nudged in between.

Comment: erm.....can be math and physics question.

Answer (score 1):

dBm is an abbreviation for the power ratio in decibels (dB) of the measured power referenced to one milliwatt (mW). So if $P$ is a power expressed in Watt ($P_{\rm Watt}$), then $P$ expressed in dBm is
$$
P_{\textrm{dBm}}=10\log_{10}\left(\frac{P_{\rm Watt}}{1\text{mW}}\right)=30+10\log_{10}\left(\frac{P_{\rm Watt}}{1\text{W}}\right)=30+P_{\textrm{dB}}
$$

If $\frac{\left(\text{FFT}(A)\right)^2}{50}$ represents a power, then it is correct.